# WP-Query : check if the post content is empty

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to check if my post has content, in the loop. Currently, i added a condition in the loop :

```
if ( $post->post_content )
```

and putted argument in the

```
wp query ('posts_per_page' => 8).
```

I thought it worked, but actually, `WP query` go find last `8 posts`, and check the content of those `8 lasts`. So it renders `2` or `3` posts.

The thing I want is a way to show last `8` posts that has content.

See what I mean ?

I really appreciate some help :)

Best regards.

Comment: You mean, query returns 8 post, but only 2 or 3 are rendered ? If it is, add empty check also in your query.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't possible with a standard WP query, and you'll have to leverage the use of `posts_where` before the WP_Query is called.

```
function filter_where($where = ''){
    return $where .= "AND trim(coalesce(post_content, '')) <>''";
}
```

In the above, we're simply only selecting posts where the column `post_content` isn't empty.

Then add the filter.

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Now perform the query.

```
$query = new WP_Query(array('post_type' => 'post', 'posts_per_page' => 8));
```

And then when you're done, remove the filter from the query so it doesn't interfere.

```
remove_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');
```

Comment: Ok, i guess i get it. Thanks a lot !